# Keras Tensorflow error: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am running this very simple code, creating a LSTM layer in a Sequential model in Keras:

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(2,3)))
```

And I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm_8/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. 
This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

The software versions:

Python 3.9.7

Tensorflow 2.4.1

Keras 2.4.0

Numpy 1.21.2

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Show the rest of your code

Comment: to be honest anything I try to do gives that error.. also check this https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/

from keras.models import Model

from keras.layers import Input

from keras.layers import LSTM

from numpy import array

inputs1 = Input(shape=(3, 1))

lstm1 = LSTM(1)(inputs1)

model = Model(inputs=inputs1, outputs=lstm1)

data = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]).reshape((1,3,1))

print(model.predict(data))

Comment: This error is likely because of `Numpy` version. For Tensorflow 2.4.1 support Numpy  1.19.2. `pip install numpy==1.19.2` will solve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: install tensorflow-gpu 2.5 automatically install numpy 1.21.2 an cause the same error... removing this version of numpy to re-install 1.19.2 cause removing tensorflow... I'm turning around since 2 week with this prob of version... cant find a compatible tensorflow-numpy-pandas-sklearn-matplotlib compatibility. Im on conda

Comment: For me it actually worked by `conda install numpy==1.19.2` and did not remove tensorflow.